For a finite dimensional vector space $V$, how does a basis of $V^*$ induce a basis of $V$?
Of course, given a basis of $V$, we can construct a dual basis for $V^*$ in the finite dimensional setting.
Does the other direction hold in some capacity?
For context, the sentence straddling pages 278-9 of Lee's Smooth Manifolds, 2nd ed. claims that we can go from a local coframe to a dual local frame. In fact, he claims that, if $\epsilon^i$ indicates covector fields comprising the coframe, then we can find vector fields $E_j$s such that $\epsilon^i(E_j) = \delta^i_j$.

This is what I have so far:
This might be unconstructive.
Fix some $j$, I will show that $E_j \in V$ exists and is unique (consider $\epsilon^i \in V^*$).
First, I show that it is unique. Otherwise, we can find $E_j, E_j'$ such that $\epsilon^j(E_j) = \epsilon^j(E_j') = 1$. But then, it follows that $\epsilon^j(E_n-E_j') = 0$, which is bad, as $\{\epsilon^i\}$ was supposed to be a dual basis.
Now, I show the existence of such an $E_j$. Clearly, it suffices for us to show that there exists some $E_j$ such that $\epsilon^j(E_j) \neq 0$, but that $\epsilon^i(E_j) = 0$ for all $i \neq j$.
Suppose that no such $E_j$ existed. So, for each $v\in V$, either:

$\epsilon^i(v) = 0$ for all $i$;
$\epsilon^j(v) = 0$;
$\epsilon^i(v) \neq 0$ for some $i\neq j$.

As $\{\epsilon^i(v)\}$ is a dual basis, 1) can only hold for the identity element.
Then, ???

Isn't it the case that in finite-dimensional settings that $V$ and $V^*$ are canonically isomorphic? Isn't this enough? Or perhaps i'm misunderstanding the question.

$V$ and $V^*$ are non-canonically isomorphic. $V$ is canonically isomorphic to the double dual $V^{**}$.

Ah, do you mean to say that you can identify $V$ with $V^{**}$ and then conclude immediately by taking a dual basis to our basis in $V^*$?

Sure, once you have determined a map $V \to V^{**}$ and understood that it is an isomorphism (which fails for infinite-dimensional $V$, by the way).

You have a canonical embedding and isomorphism just stems from dimension counting, yup yup.
